# create two sets of multiple processes that work on different tasks python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-s3, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

there. I have been working on a problem where I need to introduce multiprocessing because the traditional approach is taking a lot of time. Here for the entire process I am creating 10 to 20 processes which takes lesser and considerable amount of time but there is one particular function where the process hits an API which sometimes take some time and if at once a lot of requests coming through it gets overwhelmed and does not return any value. At one time it can take maximum of 4 requests, so I was thinking of 4 separate processes and 10 separate processes for the tasks that I am doing and returning the result which will be considered as an input to these 4 processes and will send 4 requests at one time and then this data should be shared with other 10 processes because if the API returns the response it will be used by 10 processes to do the rest of the work like storing to s3 and everything. So, in short I want two different sets of multi processes

--> 10 for task 1 getting the s3 object reading and preprocessing and returning the result

--> 4 for task 2 to use the results and send the 4 requests at a time one request per process and return the response and share this response with the first 10 processes

--> first 10 processes will use the responses and do the rest of the remaining work like storing the new object into the s3 bucket

Now, I have tried using multiprocessing.Queue and multiprocessing.Pipe but could not work it out as expected and I was thinking of using multiprocessing.Pool but I don't know if it fits my requirement.

Can anyone please help me out?, Hope this much information helps out to understand the problem. Thanks in advance!

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def main_process(f_name):
    # getting the object from s3 bucket
    # pre-processing
    # hitting the api which can take maximum of 4 requests at once
    # rest of the work

def start_process(f):
    for f_name in f:
        main_process(f_name)

myList = ["abc.xml","def.xml",.....]  # thousands of objects
num_workers = 10
updated_myList = np.array_split(myList, num_workers)

processes = []
for val in updated_myList:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_process, args=(val,))
    p.start()
    print("process :: ",p)
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

I was thinking of something like this

```
processes = []
other_processes = []
for val in updated_myList:
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_process, args=(val,)) # 10 processes
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=other_process, args=(result_from_p1,)) # 4 processes
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    # now I don't know how to use the results from p2 for p1 again 
    print("process :: ",p1)
    processes.append(p1)
    other_processes.append(p2)

for p in processes:
    p.join()

for p in other_processes:
    p.join()
```

I want it to be done in parallel those 10 processes and 4 processes working parallelly like those 4 processes will be checking a queue and if the queue is empty it will keep on checking if the new data is inserted and if there is then it will process and send output through some queue and then accordingly 10 processes will pick the responses and do their work. But I am not aware if this is possible.

Though, There is one thing that do is I can create 10 processes and let all the processes get joined and finished their preprocessing tasks and then I will create 4 processes and then these 4 processes will use these data to get the responses and then it will be joined and finished. And then in the end I will again create 10 processes to work on the responses from the 4 processes. But this is not being done parallelly so I want those 10 processes and 4 processes work in parallel and share data where necessary.

Is there any way? Please, do let me otherwise.

Thank you all!

Comment: It sounds like your processing cannot really be done in parallel, because they are not independent.  Do you actually know what is taking the time?

Comment: @TimRoberts the number of files that are been done they are quite large in size (400K, 500K daily) and reading the s3 object and putting the object into s3 is quite fine and considerable it is just that API that I am hitting it can take only 4 requests at once due to which a lot of files gets failed to return the response from the API. so I wanted to separate these things out but make it parallel to save time.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted very sparse code so I cannot be sure for which parts of your processing that multiprocessing or multithreading would be suitable. Multiprocessing introduces overhead that does not exist when doing serial processing so the processing done by your "worker functions" must be sufficiently CPU-intensive so that the additional multiprocessing is more than offset by the time saved by running the functions in parallel. Multithreading has less overhead than multiprocessing but due to contention for the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), your worker functions cannot execute Python code in parallel. Thus, multithreading is best suited for tasks that do a lot of waiting (e.g. for disk I/O or network requests to complete) and little CPU-intensive work. Then there is the question of how many actual processors you have. If you have a multiprocessing worker function that is all CPU processing and no waiting and you have N processors, it makes no sense to create more than N processes to process this work.

That said, this is how I would approach the problem. First, I would use two multiprocessing pools, one with 10 processes and the other with 4 processes. I would use the second one for doing task 2 (which uses the results from task 1 and cannot send more than 4 simultaneous requests). The other pool would be used for performing task 1 and task 3 (which uses the results from task 2). I would then create a pipeline where the results from task 1 are fed to task 2 as they become available and the results from task 2 are fed to task 3 as those results become available. For that, using the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap` method is the most appropriate. By specifying a suitable *chunksize* argument to this call, all the "batching" or requests are done for you. You need to, of course, read the documentation on this method:

In the code below I generate demo results so you can see how everything fits together. Task 1 takes its argument (e.g. "abc.xml") and returns its length. Task 2 tasks Task 1's return value and returns twice that value. Task 3 finally takes the result from task 2 and squares it. So the first, final result should be (len("abc.xml") * 2) ** 2 = 196.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def task1(f_name):
    # for demo purposes:
    result1 = len(f_name)
    return result1

def task2(result1):
    """
    result1 is a return value from task1
    """
    result2 = result1 * 2
    return result2

def task3(result2):
    """
    result2 is a return value from task2
    """
    result3 = result2 ** 2
    return result3

def main():
    def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize

    myList = ["abc.xml","def.xml", 'etc.']  # thousands of objects
    myList_length = len(myList)

    chunksize_10 = compute_chunksize(myList_length, 10)
    chunksize_4 = compute_chunksize(myList_length, 4)

    pool_10 = Pool(10)
    pool_4 = Pool(4)
    # Preprocessing:
    result1_iterator = pool_10.imap(task1, myList, chunksize=chunksize_10)
    # Pass return values from task1 to second pool as they
    # become available:
    result2_iterator = pool_4.imap(task2, result1_iterator, chunksize=chunksize_4)
    # Submit results from task2 back to the first_pool as they
    # become available:
    result3_iterator = pool_10.imap(task3, result2_iterator, chunksize=chunksize_10)
    # Finally, iterate the results from task3 as they
    # become available
    for result3 in result3_iterator:
        # ith result should be (len(myList[i]) * 2) ** 2
        # 196, 196, 64
        print(result3)

    pool_10.close()
    pool_10.join()

    pool_4.close()
    pool_4.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
196
196
64
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will definitely try this and it seems that you understood my requirement. I wanted to add more code but most of it were confidential and I cannot share it that is why I tried to elaborate it as much as possible by writing it down.